# Select2 add image icon to option dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

This is what select2.github.io gives you:

```
function addIcons(opt) {
    if (!opt.id) {
        return opt.text;
    }
    var $opt = $(
            '<span><img src="/images/flags/' + opt.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + opt.text + '</span>'
            );
    return $opt;
}
```

I'd like to add a data-image attribute to my options:

```
<option value="flag" data-image="/images/flags/flag.png">Country 1</option>
```

and log it in the function:

```
function addIcons(opt) {
    if (!opt.id) {
        return opt.text;
    }

    var optimage = opt.attr('data-image');
    var $opt = $(
            '<span><img src="/images/flags/' + optimage + '" class="img-flag" /> ' + opt.text + '</span>'
            );
    return $opt;
}
```

Sadly, a simple console.log(opt); doesn't return anything in the function, so I can't see if I can access my data-image attribute. The above block of code returns an error, so this obviously doesn't work. Any suggestions on this matter?

Comment: An error? What's the specific error message? Do you have a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: to get the data value use $(opt.element).attr('data-image');

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solved using `attr` and tested on Select2 4.0.6-rc.0.

```
$(".class").select2({
    templateResult: formatState,
    templateSelection: formatState
});

function formatState (opt) {
    if (!opt.id) {
        return opt.text.toUpperCase();
    } 

    var optimage = $(opt.element).attr('data-image'); 
    console.log(optimage)
    if(!optimage){
       return opt.text.toUpperCase();
    } else {                    
        var $opt = $(
           '<span><img src="' + optimage + '" width="60px" /> ' + opt.text.toUpperCase() + '</span>'
        );
        return $opt;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 16):

If optimage returns "undefined" try my sample: its working fine:

```js
$("#selectUserForChat").select2({
  templateResult: addUserPic,
  templateSelection: addUserPic
});

function addUserPic(opt) {
  if (!opt.id) {
    return opt.text;
  }
  var optimage = $(opt.element).data('image');
  if (!optimage) {
    return opt.text;
  } else {
    var $opt = $(
      '<span class="userName"><img src="' + optimage + '" class="userPic" /> ' + $(opt.element).text() + '</span>'
    );
    return $opt;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 9):

I solved problem with this code: `var optimage = $(opt.element).data('image');`

```
$(".category").select2({
            templateResult: formatState,
            templateSelection: formatState
        });
        function formatState (opt) {
            if (!opt.id) {
                return opt.text;
            }               
            var optimage = $(opt.element).data('image'); 
            if(!optimage){
                return opt.text;
            } else {                    
                var $opt = $(
                    '<span><img src="' + optimage + '" width="23px" /> ' + opt.text + '</span>'
                );
                return $opt;
            }

        };
```

Comment: That is the same as in my example, and that didn't work: var optimage = opt.attr('data-image');

Comment: I try to complete answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var optimage = $(opt).data('image'); //or $(opt).attr('data-image')
var $opt = $(
    '<span><img src="' + optimage + '" class="img-flag" /> ' + $(opt).text() + '</span>'
);
```

Comment: optimage returns "undefined". I have tried it this way too.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily related to the question, but in my case it wasn't working because if you are using Select 2 < 4.0, `templateResult` and `templateSelection` does not exist. Use `formatResult` and `formatSelection` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Every single answer here is incorrect** as it exposes your application to an XSS vulnerability when returning a jQuery object to select2. [Let's read the docs and find out why](https://select2.org/dropdown#built-in-escaping):

> **Built-in escaping**
>
> By default, strings returned by `templateResult` are assumed to contain only text and will be passed through the `escapeMarkup` function, which strips any HTML markup.
>
> If you need to render HTML with your result template, you must wrap your rendered result in a jQuery object. In this case, the result will be passed directly to `jQuery.fn.append` and will be handled directly by jQuery. Any markup, such as HTML, **will not be escaped and it is up to you to escape any malicious input provided by users**.

Looking at the other answers, they all have the fatal flaw of not escaping the text before passing it back. Instead the correct code should look like this (assuming a proper `escape` function, I used lodash in my circumstance):

```js
$(".class").select2({
    templateResult: formatState,
    templateSelection: formatState
});

function formatState (opt) {
    if (!opt.id) {
        return opt.text;
    } 

    var optimage = $(opt.element).attr('data-image'); 
    if(!optimage) {
       // This is safe, since you're returning a string
       return opt.text;
    } else {
       // Create an individual image element to properly escape the src url
       var img = $("<img width='60px'>");
       img.attr("src", optimage);

       // And remember to escape the text we're outputing
       var $opt = $(
         '<span>' +
         img.prop('outerHTML'); +
         '" width="60px" /> ' + 
         escape(opt.text) + 
         '</span>'
       );
       return $opt;
    }
};
```